# "bat file" to run SQL log file shrink task

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have a SQL2012 DB that has a log file growing very rapidly. I have a 3rd party program doing full database backups so I'm not worried about that. 
I have the command to run in the SQL manager to shrink the log file and that is working but it's a very manual task.

I'm trying to create a script that I can schedule to run every 2 weeks but a BAT file won't work it seems as after the `sqlcmd -S servername\instancename -E` command is run it just goes to 1> and stops. I need to run the USE and DBCC commands but not sure how to achieve this.

I have tried looking online but nowhere can I find a way to make a double click script to run this `DBCC SHRINKFILE` task.

So using sqlcmd, I can do this:

```
USE DBNAME
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (DBNAME_20070302091322_Log, 1);
GO
```

Running manually the file shrinks to below 10mb and that is correct. I need to just automate this task.

Comment: please have a look at this `What’s So Bad About Shrinking Databases with DBCC SHRINKDATABASE?` https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/

Comment: `sqlcmd` has a `-d db_name` parameter to specify the database name. Please see the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Your 3rd party program needs to do transaction log backups as well. This is what will prevent your logfile from growing infinitely. Shrinking anything "manually" is not the correct solution here. If you're only taking `FULL` backups but no transaction log backups, you may as well just switch your database to `SIMPLE` recovery.

Comment: @alroc Simple might work but i need the logs. I do a full DB backup on Mondays and then i do log backups on tuesdays to fridays as the log is supposed to be smaller. So my idea is to just shrink the log file on saturdays so if the DB crashed on a wednesday i can restore the DB and run the log and be right back to where i was with maybe just a few hours worth of missing pieces.

Comment: OK, so how much of your transaction log space is actually in use? The log is cleared after a log backup is properly completed, so if it's grown to a particular size _and_ you're taking regular log backups, that's the size needed to accommodate your log backup schedule. If you want smaller logs, increase the frequency of your log backups, and make sure you aren't taking copy-only log backups. You're wasting resources trying to shrink a logfile that's going to grow right back to its original size.

Comment: @alroc I see.. Look im still a complete SQL newb so ill have to study up a bit as it seems im missing the mark quite a bit here. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

> I have a SQL2012 DB that has a log file growing very rapidly

In this case you must verify the database **recovery model** and `log_reuse_wait_desc` which you can identity with following command:

```
Select name, recovery_model_desc, log_reuse_wait_desc
from sys.databases
```

**If Recovery model set to FULL:**

As mentioned in the comments, you must schedule `LOG BACKUP` at the backup tool that you are using for Full Backups, even you perform `DBCC SHRINKFILE` it would't shrink the size due to active portion in the log file, you must perform appropriate action bases on `log_reuse_wait_desc` status before running `DBCC SHRINKFILE` command. You can verify it
looking at message section once `DBCC` command you executed.

[For more details on LOG FILE/CHECKPOINTS/`log_reuse_wait`..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

**If Recovery model set to Simple:**

Once you decided to go with **Simple** recovery model, shrink the file manually, but keep enough room for SQL Engine to perform log operations depending on transaction workload. Shrinking the log file to lower size means putting unnecessary overload on the server as the SQL Engine try to increase it again when there is no enough space available for the transaction workload/throughput.

You do not have schedule `LOG backup` in simple recovery model, as the log file checkpoints would be automatically added and based on checkpoint log would be truncated.

Answer (score -1):

So looks like with your help i managed to get it working. 
I have a BAT with the -i option where the DBCC command is.

here is that bat

sqlcmd -S sqlserver\instance -E -d databasename -i c:\test.sql -o c:\out.txt

here is hte test.sql

USE databasename
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (DBLOGFILENAME_Log, 1);
GO

tested and its working.

Comment: This is still the wrong solution to whatever problem you think you're solving.

Comment: @alroc so after I managed to get the APP working again because the log file was sitting at 500gb using my DBCC SHRINK file hack I went on to find out more about how the backup app is doing the backups and what the exact settings are as this is stuff that was all given to me after the fact and I was not part of the setup or anything. I managed the change the recovery model to full, change the backup app to do log backups to the cloud as well and changed the max size of the LOG to DB size plus 10GB . so IF i understand it all correctly my log file should no longer be an issue.